# Save XML nested child nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, nested, xquery-sql

I have a Problem with saving the XML nodes in different Tables.
I want to save the Listnodes in one Table(ListsSet) and the Columnsnodes in another Table(ColumnsSet) which is referencing the ListTable. But in the Columnsnode is also a DependentLookupField childnode. I want to save the value from the DependentLookupField in a third Table(DependentLookupFieldsSet), which is referencing the ColumnTable.

My XML:

```
<Lists>
<List title="test">
  <ListUrl>fsasa</ListUrl>
  <ListTitle>gsdfgsg</ListTitle>
  <ListDesc>jasdh</ListDesc>
  <Columns>
    <Column action="modify">
      <InternalName>Title</InternalName>
      <DisplayNameOrigin>Titel</DisplayNameOrigin>
      <DisplayName>Name</DisplayName>
    </Column>
    <Column action="new">
      <Required>true</Required>
      <FieldType>Choice</FieldType>
      <InternalName>anrede</InternalName>
      <DisplayName>Anrede</DisplayName>
    </Column>
    <Column action="add" type="sitecolumn">
      <Required>true</Required>
      <InternalName>Bank</InternalName>
      <DisplayName>Bank</DisplayName>
      <MultipleValues>0</MultipleValues>
      <DependentLookupFields>
        <DependentLookupField internalName="Title">My Value</DependentLookupField>
      </DependentLookupFields>
    </Column>
  </Columns>
</List>
<List>
 .
 .
 .
 etc
</List>
</Lists>
```

My Code of the Stored Procedure:

```
INSERT INTO ListsSet
SELECT 
List.value('ListUrl[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS ListURL, 
List.value('ListTitle[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS ListTitle, 
List.value('ListDesc[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS ListDesc,
FROM
@xml.nodes('/Lists/List')AS TEMPTABLE(List)

INSERT INTO ColumnsSet
SELECT 
l.ListsID, 
c.value('FieldType[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS FieldType,
c.value('InternalName[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS InternalName,
c.value('DisplayName[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS DisplayName,
c.value('Required[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS Required,
c.value('DisplayNameOrigin[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS DisplayNameOrigin,
c.value('MultipleValues[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS MultipleValues,
FROM
ListsSet AS l
cross apply @xml.nodes('/Lists/List/Columns/Column[../../ListUrl=sql:column("l.ListUrl")]') AS TEMPTABLE(c) 

INSERT INTO DependentLookupFieldsSet
SELECT
c.ColumnsID,
d.value('DependentLookupField[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS DependetLookupField
FROM
ColumnsSet AS c
cross apply @xml.nodes('/Lists/List/Columns/Column/DependentLookupFields/DependentLookupField[../../InternalName=sql:column("c.InternalName")]') AS TEMPTABLE(d)
```

The Code for saving the Listsnodes and Columnsnode is working fine. But the Code for the DependentLookupField don't save the value. In the Table "DependentLookupFieldsSet" I get the Rows which are referencing the ColumsTable(that is working), but the saved value is always null in each row.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I think you should change `d.value('DependentLookupField[1]'...` to `d.value('.', ...` ;).

Comment: Thanks, that works for me.